# Find the last element present in the array via Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to work on restricting people who are able to like the posts on an application built on firebase.

I need to verify if the last element of the array exists.
However, I am unable to find the last element present inside array.

I have an array 'Likes' in cloud firestore which has 2 parts - userName and userId

How will I be able to find the last userId present in the array via firestore rules

I have tried below as can be done in python but doesnt work -

```
request.resource.data.likes[-1].userId
```

Answer (score 2):

What you call an array, is actually known as a [`List` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) in Firestore security rules. This type indeed does not recognize negative offsets (honestly: most systems I know of don't), but you can get the same by using `size`.

So something like:

```
request.resource.data.likes[request.resource.data.likes.size()-1].userId
```